# How to multiply Mat A * B?

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I am trying to multiply two Mat type A and B (gray scaled) without using multiply() function.
so far I developed below code and it does not work. I checked with multiply(A,B,AB) function it worked but the below code did not work.

```
Mat A,B,AB, src;
float AB_yx;
src = imread("as.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
Sobel(src , A, CV_32FC1 , 1, 0, 3, BORDER_DEFAULT);
Sobel(src , B, CV_32FC1 , 0, 1, 3, BORDER_DEFAULT);
// multiply(A, B, AB); //worked
AB= src.clone();

for (int y = 0; y < A.rows; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < B.cols; x++) {
         AB_yx= 0;
         for (int y = 0; y < B.rows; y++) {
         // for (int k = 0; k < B.rows; k++) {

            AB.at<float>(y, x) = A.at<float>(y, x) * B.at<float>(y, x); //sturkmen's method
            //AB_yx = AB_yx + A.at<float>(y, k) * B.at<float>(k, x);//
        }
        //AB.at<float>(y, x) = AB_yx; 
    }
}




namedWindow("AB");
imshow("AB", AB);
```

**issue visual studio gives abort() has been called**

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (((((sizeof(size_t)<<28)|0x8442211) >> ((DataType<_Tp>::depth) & ((1 << 3) - 1))*4) & 15) == elemSize1()) in cv::Mat::at, file d:\opencv\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp, line 957
```

Comment: "below code did not work" Can you be more specific?

Comment: Do you know how to multiply matrices?

Comment: The code you wrote does a per-member multiplication, not matrix multiplication. It's the wrong algorithm altogether.

Comment: You can just write `AB = A * B`, if matrix multiplication is what you need.

Comment: Now you completely changed your code.

Comment: i made the code correct way as use in c to multiply two matrices. still it doesn't compile on visual studio it asks to abort.

Comment: Is it the code which doesnt compile or now something else ?

Comment: Why do you think `AB.cols` has anything to do with the number of columns in `A` or the number of rows in `B`? You need to clear your accumulator before using it.

Comment: @Hannes Hauptmann i tried same variables A and B with multiply(A,B,AB) function it works and gave the out put AB image as per requirement. and i need to do it without multiply() function.

Comment: Can you show us your full function? There's a lot of missing code here. How is AB created? What is AB_yx? see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Frank  AB_yx is as in c matrix multiplication we have sum. sum is int type [see link](http://www.c4learn.com/c-programs/c-program-to-multiply-two-3-x-3.html)

Comment: @komto909 You need to show us the code that won't compile in a way that we can reproduce your error, otherwise, we cannot help you.

Comment: i do not get an error, the visual studio asks to abort compilation. i need to implement multiply() function in a c language. that is what i have tried to do in above code.

Comment: @komto909 The problem remains: you need to give us your full `multiply()` function. Unless we can reproduce the compiler aborting, we simply do not have enough information to help you.

Comment: @Frank multiply() is not a my function..... its the function that provide by opencv i have mentioned that **multiply Mat type A * B without using opencv functions**

Comment: I don't understand.  You say you need function in C language but you tagged with C++; different languages.  For example, you can overload operators in C++ and C++ has `std::vector`.

Comment: @komto909 I meant **your** function, containing the snipet of code in your post, that you are using as a replacement for opencv's `multiply()`

Comment: Your matrix multiplication algorithm is implemented incorrectly.  Search the internet for "C matrix multiplication example".

Comment: Post your complete function finally. This is like tapping in the dark.

Comment: I said clearly I used multiply function to multiply Mat A and Mat B gray scaled images... and i am trying to do it manually using matrix multiplication method in c... that is all no other code is there... there is no **my function** I am trying to implement my own function

Comment: @komto909 What we are saying is that the posted code is clearly not the totality of your attempt. We need to see the lines of code where you declare AB and AB_yx, we need to know how A and B were declared, we need to know how AB is passed on to the rest of the code. We are not even sure what the type of any of these variables are. Your error is most likely in that missing code, and we cannot help you wihtout you giving it to us.

Comment: I updated the code that is whole code !

Comment: @komto909 Does matrix multiplication of two images even make sense?  Are you sure your algorithm does not call for element-wise multiplication?  Everyone seems to be jumping to implementing correct matrix multiplication, but my crystal ball is telling me that you don't actually want that.

Comment: @Peter: That is an excellent point. I am deleting my answer.

Comment: can you find out at which line that abort happens? Can you verify that the image was successfully loaded with `if(src.empty()) printSomeErrorMessageAndExit();` right after imread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is to improve concept

```
    Mat A = (Mat_<float>(3, 4) << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3);
    Mat B = (Mat_<float>(3, 4) << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3);

    Mat AB0;
    multiply(A, B, AB0);
    cout << A << endl;
    cout << B << endl;
    cout << AB0 << endl;
    Mat AB1 = Mat(A.size(), CV_32FC1);

        for (int x = 0; x < B.cols; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < B.rows; y++)
            {
                AB1.at<float>(y, x) = A.at<float>(y, x) * B.at<float>(y, x);
            }
        }

    cout << AB1 << endl;
```

this should work to you

```
Mat A, B, AB, src;
src = imread("as.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
Sobel(src, A, CV_32FC1, 1, 0, 3, BORDER_DEFAULT);
Sobel(src, B, CV_32FC1, 0, 1, 3, BORDER_DEFAULT);

AB = Mat(A.size(), CV_32FC1);

for (int x = 0; x < B.cols; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < B.rows; y++)
    {
        AB.at<float>(y, x) = A.at<float>(y, x) * B.at<float>(y, x);
    }
}


namedWindow("AB");
imshow("AB", AB);
waitKey();
```

but keep in mind that this code will work slow. you need use pointers to speed up the process

Comment: still same issue visual studio gives **abort() has been called**

Comment: i tried your final code it worked and i got the output, but i still get that issue  **abort() has been called**

Comment: I updated the code. and i tried same code you have given it worked but got that abort(). then did changes in my code with images still no output and got abort()

Comment: for (int y = 0; y < B.cols; y++) should be  for (int y = 0; y < B.rows; y++)

Answer (score 0):

The bigest problem comes from the management of the `int AB_yx;` variable. It's uninitialized, and should also be reset to 0 at the start of each `x` iteration.

Another issue is that `AB` is also used uninitialized, you should resize it to the proper dimension before you start assigning data at arbitrary indices inside it.

Comment: I did the changes, did not compile same issue

Answer (score 0):

`AB.at<float>` is wrong, since `AB` is a copy of `src` which is most probably a `CV_8UC1 matrix`, so it must be `AB.at<uchar>` or you'll have to convert `AB` first to `float` (`CV_32FC1`)